# React Native Project Cloned from Git keeps opening SampleApp

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have an existing React Native project in Bitbucket. Today I cloned it by overwriting a project I had created with `react-native init <name>`.

Build runs smoothly and it opens the app. But instead of showing my `index.ios.js` it shows the text "Welcome to React Native!", which seems to be same as `/Examples/SampleApp`. I already removed that folder, but it still keeps popping up.

What should I do to point to my own `index.ios.js` and to get my project up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You might have the packager opened with the SampleApp in separate XCode project. just make sure that you stop it. That's one of the minor problems with React that by default (unless you change port numbers in the code of your app) you cannot have two react apps running in parallel.

Comment: I think this was the issue. I closed all the possible windows, removed the whole project and then did my stuff again from scratch and it started to work.